# Is there a one click dictionary app for Opera browser as in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: browser, browser-addons

There is this wonderful one click dictionary extension for firefox and chrome with the help of which I can know the meanings of any words on a web page on the fly. This extensions searches the dictionary meaning for the word I double click on the web page. I see that there is no such extension for Opera browser. When I double click a word on the web page it shows up an annoying pop up that asks me to search the meaning on google/dictionary, etc.

Is there an easy look up dictionary extension in Opera as in chrome and firefox?

PS: I am certainly not looking for Opera dictionary widget as an option because it is rather annoying that I copy paste the word on the web page into the widget and search for its meaning.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very useful extension: **[HyperTranslate](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/hypertranslate/2.3.0/)**

After installing it you can change some settings. For example, use "Double click a word" to translate by double clicking one word, or set key to press to translate a sentence. You should first deactivate Opera's pop-up menu on double clicking (advanced settings-> panels->check-box).

Comment: "This extension is only supported in Opera 11 and 12." - Not useful for me. :(